# Rails 4 model subfolder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, subdirectory

I'm created model in app/models/request/book folder but Book::Request::Status.table_name returns table name "statuses" ("book_request_statuses" - is right table name). How I can get correct table name?

**model location**

```
model/
  book/
    request/
      status.rb
```

**model/book/request/status.rb**

```
class Book::Request::Status < ActiveRecord::Base
...
end
```

**config/application.rb**

```
config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'models', '**', '*.rb')]
```

If I set self.table_name = "book_request_statuses" then the model will work correctly (in model), but it's not good way :).

sorry for my English is not good

Comment: I think there is no other answer to your question.. Just specify table name in the model and it works like you want.

Comment: ok, thank you. Rails 3 don't have this problem...

Answer (score 4):

1) Create a module in app/models/book.rb with these lines.

```
module Book
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'book_'
  end
end
```

2) Then create another module in app/models/book/request.rb

```
module Request
  def self.table_name_prefix
    'request_'
  end
end
```

3) Put the status model inside the app/models/book/request/ directory.

4) Keep all the other files intact.

I hope that works for you.

Comment: I should add. I just tried calling `rails g model request/book/status` and it generated the items in this answer. It also generated the correct migration. So I would suggest doing that to make it a bit easier :). Cheers.